# Is there a way to visualize the process of source() in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I apply source() on a .R file, it is usually very time-consuming when the .R file involves big data and multiple steps. If I could see which line it is that R is currently running on, or the percentage of completion, it would be a lot more easier for RStudio users anyway (Similar to running a r chunk in R Markdown). Is that feasible? Or is there already a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push the 'Source' button in RStudio, it automatically generates and executes the code `source(path.to.current.file, echo=TRUE)`. If you look at the help for `source` (`?source`), you will see that it has a `verbose` parameter. Setting this to `TRUE` will cause each command to be printed to the console as it is executed.

e.g. assuming you have a script called "script.R" in the home directory you could run:

```
source('~/script.R', verbose=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much